# Puzzling Struggle in building Jitsi from Source

Tags: webrtc, jitsi, video-conferencing, jitsi-meet

In a few words: this dilemma is about a Jitsi build from source. Are things still only working using docker? Feels unimaginable really. Can’t tell you how much any hints/suggestions would be valued.

Have followed the steps from the post (https://community.jitsi.org/t/how-to-how-to-build-jitsi-meet-from-source-a-developers-guide/75422) and things only work locally.

More background info: Truly EVERYTHING was looked into in terms of discussions out there. Tried on GCP, AWS and Vultr.

Thank you.
Cheers

Comment: I know you are having issues building from source but Vultr does offer a 1 click install of Jitsi if you want to get up and running quick.

https://www.vultr.com/apps/jitsi

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'm afraid that there wouldn't be a way around that